# Lista circular simple (NO NODOS)

Tags: lista, nodos, modular

Disculpen, alguien tiene idea de cómo crear una lista circular simple sin usar nodos, solamente usando un arreglo de números (enteros), llevo buen rato probando y no encuentro una solucion que no sea usando nodos. Se deben poder eliminar elementos y "recorrerlos" para agregar un nuevo elemento al final de la lista (Bueno, ésto se hace por medio de un menú, pero no es relevante). Es un programa para la universidad y la recomendación de nuestro profesor es usar aritmética modular para encontrar el sucesor y antecesor dentro de la lista circular. Obviamente son varios modulos y cada uno realiza una tarea. Agrego la información para realizar el programa:

*Ejercicio: Desarrolla un programa para soportar un TDA lista (estática) de enteros, mediante un arreglo de 7 localidades, gestionado con aritmética modular. Que ofrezca las siguientes operaciones:
Una función "full()", que devuelve 1 si la lista está llena, y 0 en otro caso
Una función "element(i)", que devuelve el valor contenido en la i-ésima posición, o VACIO, si la lista no contiene elemento en esa posición. OJO: no lo remueve, sólo toma una copia del valor almacenado.
Una función "insert(x)" que inserta el valor "x" al final de la lista y devuelve 1 si esto se se realiza con éxito, o 0 si no es posible
Una función "remove(i)" que elimina el el valor contenido en la i-ésima posición, o VACIO, si la lista no contiene elemento en esa posición.
Un procedimiento main() desde el que se puede invocar cualquiera de las funciones anteriores.*

**Todo lo anterior debe realizarse sin usar Nodos**

***NOTA: El tamaño del arreglo siempre es constante***

Pueden ayudarme o darme una recomendación
Gracias :)!!

Comment: Hasta donde yo entiendo tienes que definirte un array estático tuarray[TU_SIZE], de tamaño constante (el que quieras) y sabiendo el tamaño, puedes considerar cuando está lleno, meter elementos nuevos hasta el tamaño máximo, retornar el elemento de una posición. Piénsalo un poco que es muy sencillo. Necesitas el array, el tamaño del array y un valor para inicializar los huecos del array que no tengas posicionados (por ejemplo, si seteas cada posición con valor -1 cuando no tienen valor asignado, te valdrá para saber si la posición está o no vacía). Inténtalo y vuelve con las dudas que tengas.

Comment: Pues la verdad no sé cómo lo hice, pero funcionó bien. Usando un apuntador a inicio, un apuntador a fin y un caracter para un lugar vacío. Pero pues salió.
Muchas gracias!!